# non-free opencv algorithms missing despite included in cmake

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, sift, opencv-contrib

using the opencv sift feature in my python3 script gives me:

`error: (-213:The function/feature is not implemented) This algorithm is patented and is excluded in this configuration; Set OPENCV_ENABLE_NONFREE CMake option and rebuild the library in function 'create'`

But this option was set and the cmake output said

`Non-free algorithms: YES"`

therefore I assume the flag was correct. The output regarding python3 is:

`--     Interpreter: /Users/andre/.virtualenvs/dl4cv/bin/python (ver 3.7.6)
--     Libraries: /usr/local/opt/python/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/config-3.7m-darwin/libpython3.7.dylib (ver 3.7.6)
--     numpy: /Users/andre/.virtualenvs/dl4cv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numpy/core/include (ver 1.18.0)
--     packages path: lib/python3.7/site-packages`

which looks fine to me. Everything is set up and running in a virtualenv but I can't figure out while I can't use sift. Can anyone provide some guidance?

Comment: I think that `sift` is in the contrib modules, did your opencv has compiled with contrib?

Comment: yes, the cmake output includes:
`--   Extra modules:
--     Location (extra): /Users/andre/opencv_contrib/modules`

Comment: Are you sure your virtual env is using the OpenCV you built and not from PyPI or similar? You can check the version and path of `cv2` and make sure it matches your build.